# why mpirun duplicates the program by default?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I am new to openMPI, I have problem understanding the concepts. (I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057953/what-is-easier-to-learn-and-debug-openmp-or-mpi) pretty helpful)

1- Could anyone breifly explain why we use openMPI? To my understanding, OpenMPI is used to parallelize those sections of the code which can run in parallel.

2- why `mpirun` duplicates a single program? simply because my laptop is dual core?

3 - what changes in the code I need to apply to make it run correctly? I mean ONE program parallelized on two available cores? not 2 similar threads of the same program.

Answer (score 1):

MPI is primarily of benefit when used in a multiple machine environment, in which you must run multiple processes.

It requires heavy modification of the program.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So do I need to install and use openMP instead? and your reply basically means openMPI can NOT be used for shared memory multi-threading?

Comment: OpenMP also requires modification, but not as much (arguably) as MPI. OpenMP only runs on a single machine, so the degree of parallelization will be limited by the number of cores on one machine. So if that works for you, then yes.

Comment: thanks, so it is not as easy as like adding `#pragma omp parallel for` for heavy for loops!

Comment: Well, if you already have a lot of suitable loops like that, then it can be as easy as that.

Comment: then what would be the difference of openMPI and openMP? I mean can I still use openMPI and add `pragma` on suitable loops?

Comment: OpenMP can't be distributed to multiple machines in a cluster, so the scalability is limited. [Here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_mpi/parallel_prog_compare.html) are a few points.

Comment: Yes, you can combine OpenMP and MPI. Note that OpenMP is a standard, and MPI is a standard but OpenMPI is a specific implementation of MPI. (Kind of confusing.)

Comment: Thanks, things are making better sense now.